# How do I determine if an application is running using wsadmin Jython script?

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I can get a list of instlled applications but how do I get the status using Jython?

Comment: I would also expand your question to see what the status of an application is per application server. Then we should get some more interesting answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I dont think there is any direct method to get the application running status, You can get the object from the AdminControl using the following code

```
serverstatus = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=Application,name='your_application_name',*')
print serverstatus
```

If `serverstatus` returns null, then the application is not running, if the application is running then the details of the applications would be printed.

Comment: Can you add in other arguments like `server=WPS00` or anything like that?

Comment: Answered my own question. You include in the search string `process=WPS00` and it'll look at specific AppServers.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use based on Snehan's answer.

```
import string

def getAppStatus(appName):
    # If objectName is blank, then the application is not running.
    objectName = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=Application,name=' + appName + ',*')
    if objectName == "":
        appStatus = 'Stopped'
    else:
        appStatus = 'Running'
    return appStatus

def appStatusInfo():
    appsString = AdminApp.list()
    appList = string.split(appsString, '\r\n')

    print '============================'
    print ' Status |    Application   '
    print '============================'

    # Print apps and their status
    for x in appList:
        print getAppStatus(x) + ' | ' + x

    print '============================'



appStatusInfo()
```

Sample output

```
============================
 Status |    Application
============================
Running | DefaultApplication
Running | IBMUTC
Stopped | some-ear
Running | another-ear
============================
```

Comment: So, my web console says the application is in a partial start, but when I use wsadmin scripting, it returns all the AppServers that its installed on, not actually showing a NULL, or blank return. Should that be happening?

Comment: How do I run this file? I am getting error
 NameError: name 'AdminApp' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

The following IBM documentation should help:

- WAS InfoCenter: [Querying the application state using wsadmin scripting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/txml_appstate.html)
- IBM Technote: [Listing enterprise application status using wsadmin script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207255)

To summarize, if the application is running on an application server, an [`Application` MBean](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2FApplication.html) will be registered. In order to determine if the application is running, you can query for the presence of these MBeans.

Answer (score 1):

There is some more modification required in Matthieu, Cormier's script.

Here we go.

It will work in any line separator. Generally **AdminApp.list()** will use "\" as the line seperator

```
import string

def getAppStatus(appName):
    # If objectName is blank, then the application is not running.
    objectName = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=Application,name='+ appName+',*')
    if objectName == "":
        appStatus = 'Stopped'
    else:
        appStatus = 'Running'
    return appStatus

def appStatusInfo():
    Apps=AdminApp.list().split(java.lang.System.getProperty("line.separator"))

    print '============================'
    print ' Status |    Application   '
    print '============================'

    # Print apps and their status
    for x in Apps:
        print "X value", x
        print getAppStatus(x) + ' | ' + x

    print '============================'



appStatusInfo()
```