# Wsadmin distinguish between starting application and started application

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I have an application that requires a long initialization before being completely deployed to a Webserver (WebSphere 8.5 for our use case). This initialization takes several minutes even out to half an hour and that is completely normal. I have been using the wsadmin command line tool to upload the ear file and then issue start for the application. Since the start time is long, wsadmin receives a read time exception and closes before the completion of the application initialization. If at this moment I issue a wsadmin command to see the status of the application:

```
wsadmin.sh -host $HOST -port $PORT -user $USER -password $PASS -c '$AdminControl completeObjectName type=Application,name='$APP',*'
```

I will get an answer meaning the application is running (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftxml_appstate.html)
The same answer I get when the initialization has been completed.
So the question is how to determine the exact status of my application.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I have already seen this post ([How to get current application state from wsadmin console for WebSphere 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910511/how-to-get-current-application-state-from-wsadmin-console-for-websphere-7-0)) but I am not sure how exactly I could follow the steps he is mentioning. Also I am running a single node and not a cluster.
P.S.2. Also is it possible to increase the time out for the wsadmin tool in the first place so as to avoid the read time out?

Comment: The steps he is mentioning in the post would be applicable if you have a clustered environment. A partially started status would only indicate that the application is started on some nodes but not all, which will not help you if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I hope the following can help in regards to connection timeouts: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.bpc.doc%2Fdoc%2Fbpc%2Ft5_timeouts.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did not have the time to try it but as soon as I have the chance.