# how to find status of applications in websphere

Tags: websphere

how to find status of all applications on all nodes in clustered environment + websphere?

WE have command to find applications health on a server using command `SHOW_WAS -q`

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910511/how-to-get-current-application-state-from-wsadmin-console-for-websphere-7-0

Comment: No....I want to verify the status off all applications in a cluster environment using any unix command from any one server in that environment

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to write a wsadmin script that connects to the deployment manager and gets a list of all the apps, then queries their status one by one as described here: [How do I determine if an application is running using wsadmin Jython script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185866/how-do-i-determine-if-an-application-is-running-using-wsadmin-jython-script).